# Как перехватить исключение scanner

Tags: java

Нужно сложить числа. Числа в диапазоне от 1000 до -1000.Как перехватить исключение?

Comment: в задаче сказано обязательно использовать обработку исключений?

Answer (score 1):

Для ввода используйте short a = Short.valueOf(scn.nextLine()); и отлавливайте NumberFormatException

Comment: можно после исключения по новой запустить считывание переменных?